# Localization of Data Pager control in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, datapager

Is it possible to localize DataPager control in asp.net?

Among the fields `NextPreviousPagerField` can be localized since it offers properties such as `FirstPageText` and `LastPageText`. But I am having trouble localizing `NumericPagerField`. It basically produces the page numbers and I can't find any way of localizing those.

I have tried changing the culture of current thread, but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you try `PreviousPageText="<%$Resources:TestSiteResources, PreviousPageText %>"`?

Answer (score 0):

There are also properties `PreviousPageText` and `NextPageText` in [NumericPagerField](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.numericpagerfield) control that can be localized as follows (Assuming you are using Resources):

```
<asp:NumericPagerField 
    PreviousPageText="<%$Resources:TestSiteResources, PreviousPageText %>"
    NextPageText="<%$Resources:TestSiteResources, NextPageText %>"
    ... />
```

Also note that:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.numericpagerfield.nextpagetext#remarks

> The value of this property is stored in view state. It can be saved
> automatically to a resource file by using a designer tool. For more
> information, see [LocalizableAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.localizableattribute) and [Globalization and
> Localization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/c6zyy3s9(v=vs.100)).